# jOOQ Subquery gives compile error "The method where(Condition...) in the type SelectWhereStep....is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I receive the following compiler error on the .where of the subquery (*.where( parentHelp.SUBJECT_ID = IFS_HELP.PARENT_SUBJECT_ID )*):

> The method where(Condition...) in the type SelectWhereStep<Record1<String>> is not applicable for the arguments (TableField<IfsHelpRecord,Long>)

when I have the following jOOQ subquery code:

> ```
>         IfsHelp parentHelp = IFS_HELP.as( "parentHelp" );
>
>         Field<Object> parent_help_subject = sqlca   .select( IFS_HELP.SUBJECT_NAME )
>                                                     .from( parentHelp )
>                                                     .where( parentHelp.SUBJECT_ID = IFS_HELP.PARENT_SUBJECT_ID )
>                                                     .asField( "parent_help_subject" );
>
>         results = sqlca .select( IFS_HELP.SUBJECT_NAME, IFS_HELP.SUBJECT_ID, parent_help_subject )
>                         .from( IFS_HELP )
>                         .where( IFS_HELP.HELP_TEXT.like( argument ) )
>                         .and( IFS_HELP.DISPLAY.equal( "Y" ) )
>                         .orderBy( IFS_HELP.SUBJECT_NAME.asc() )
>                         .limit( 50 )
>                         .fetch();
> ```

The database table looks like this:

```
IFS_HELP
  SUBJECT_ID (bigint, pk)
  SUBJECT_NAME (varchar)
  PARENT_SUBJECT_ID (bigint, fk back to ifs_help.subject_id)
  HELP_TEXT (varchar)
  DISPLAY (char)
```

This is the query I am trying to execute:

> ```
>    SELECT         ifs_help.subject_name,   
>                         ifs_help.subject_id,
>                         ifs_isNull( ( select subject_name from ifs_help P where P.subject_id = ifs_help.parent_subject_id ), '' ) as parent_help_subject  
>          FROM       ifs_help  
>          WHERE      ifs_help.help_text like argument
>             AND     ifs_help.display = 'Y'
>          ORDER BY   ifs_help.subject_name ASC  
>          LIMIT 50
> ```

Comment: For anyone viewing this in the future for an example, there is also a typo in my subquery.  I should have used the alias name in the select.  Field<Object> parent_help_subject = sqlca   .select( **parent_help_subject**.SUBJECT_NAME )
                                                    .from( parentHelp )
                                                    .where( parentHelp.SUBJECT_ID = IFS_HELP.PARENT_SUBJECT_ID )
                                                    .asField( "parent_help_subject" );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple typo. It would be great if the following were possible in an internal DSL like jOOQ:

```java
.where( parentHelp.SUBJECT_ID = IFS_HELP.PARENT_SUBJECT_ID )
//                            ^ Redefined semantics of assignment operator
```

But it isn't. You cannot redefine the semantics of the assignment operator in Java. So you have to use the [`eq()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#eq-org.jooq.Field-) or [`equal()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#equal-org.jooq.Field-) method instead:

```java
.where( parentHelp.SUBJECT_ID.eq(IFS_HELP.PARENT_SUBJECT_ID) )
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks!   I must have stared at that for a two hours and it was right there.   Appreciate the quick answer!